# Changing the Shared Secret in AES Encryption

Tags: .net, encryption

I have used Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) to encrypt my data before storing them into database. 
To my understanding, if I change the "Shared Secret" part of the algorithm, I have to update all of the stored data accordingly. 
Is there any other way for me to give my admin user the opportunity to  update the key without needing to update the huge volume of the stored data while doing so?

following is the code I'm using for encryption:

```
public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // prepend the IV
                msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return outStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is encrypted using one key ("Key A"), then the only way to change the key (so that it can be decrypted with e.g. "Key B") would be to decrypt *all* the data using "Key A" and then re-encrypt it using "Key B".

I believe that the general technique used to avoid this issue is to encrypt the data using a strong "master key", then encrypt the master key using the user's key. As a result, changing the password requires only decrypting and re-encrypting the master key with the old and new keys (respectively), with the data itself remaining unchanged.

You don't mention what database you're actually using, but it is probably worth noting that many database servers support automatic data encryption, so that the data stored on-disk is in an encrypted format, and cannot be decrypted and accessed unless you are an authorised user.

If the database server you're using supports this, it would be worthwhile investigating. Being transparent, you will no longer have to worry about manually encrypting/decrypting it within your code, and it will likely also already support key changing, as well as data recovery functions (should your users forget their passwords etc.)

Comment: Thanks I did some research and read about Transparent Data Encryption using master key in SQL Server. I'm still not sure that will I be able to change the masterkey on client-side or not.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the [Keyczar framework to C#](http://jbtule.github.com/keyczar-dotnet/), which has both key sets that allow you to rotate keys (encrypt only with new key and still decrypt with old) and [password encryption](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Additional-Key-Sets#pbekeyset--transforming-key-set) for the keysets.

Create key set:

```
:> KeyczarTool.exe create --location="path_to_keyset" --purpose="crypt"
:> KeyczarTool.exe addkey --location="path_to_keyset" --status="primary" --size="256" --password
Please enter password:
Please re-enter password:
```

Encrypt:

```
Func<string> passwordCallback = ()=> Console.ReadLine(); //whatever you need to prompt

using(var keySet = new KeySet("path_to_keyset"))
using(var pbeKeySet = new PbeKeySet(keySet, passwordCallback))
using(var encrypter = new Encrypter(pbeKeySet)){
{
     return encrypter.Encrypt(plaintext);
}
```

Decrypt:

```
using(var keySet = new KeySet("path_to_keyset"))
using(var pbeKeySet = new PbeKeySet(keySet, passwordCallback))
using(var crypter = new Crypter(pbeKeySet)){
{
     return crypter.Encrypt(plaintext);
}
```

Of course if you need non interactive encryption and decryption you should just go with the [regular usage](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Authenticated-Encryption) of keyczar, or you can even have a [key set to encrypt another key set](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Additional-Key-Sets#encryptedkeyset--transforming-key-set) if you need an extra level of separation.